# Title column displayed when adding new item in SP (NewForm.aspx)

Tags: title-column

I am desperately looking for an advise reg Title column topic.

over the SP list I set Allow management of content types to YES and when I click on the specific content type, I see Column A,B,C, etc....

Also on the List settings Title column is not present, so I cant hide it from that point.

Issue what I have is when I try to add an entry on that SP list, Title column is being presented. Any ideas how can I take Title column out?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be available in the interface options of the list except if it is hidden. If it is hidden, but still there you should be able to hide from the form/contenttype trough code with PNP or CSOM.

I think this link could give you all the necessary information https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-remove-title-column-from-list.html